# Where can i find cybervillansCA certificate file to bypass SSL certification?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having trouble to find the cybervillainsCA certificate file  in Selenium-Server-2.20 zip file as i only see the libs, selenium-server-2.20.0 and selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0 jar file in the folder. I need this certificate to to bypass the SSL certificates in chrome.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping in mind, the excerpt  :

> I am having trouble to find the cybervillainsCA certificate file in
>   Selenium-Server-2.20 zip file as i only see the libs,
>   selenium-server-2.20.0 and selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0 jar file
>   in the folder.

1. I understand that once you have unzipped the Selenium-Server-2.20 zip file, you would have got:

   - libs
   - **selenium-server-2.20.0**
   - selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0
2. Next you would have to extract the jar file  **"selenium-server-2.20.0"**
3. Upon extracting this jar, you would find the file cybervillainsCA in
   the folder sslSupport.
4. Open settings in chrome.
5. Open Under the hood tab.
6. Click on Manage certificates.
7. Click on import.
8. Click on Next.
9. Browse the file cybervillainsCA ( which is in sslSupport  folder as mentioned in step 3).
10. Click on Next.
11. Select Place all certificates in the following store.
12. Click on browse button.
13. Select trust root certification authorities .
14. Click on next.
15. Click on finish and then OK.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks user1316. After i posted this question, i found the solution and did whatever you mentioned out there. Thanks again. Appreciate it.

Comment: Note that since May 2016 Selenium 3.0.0 and later no longer ship with the CyberVillians certificate as the code that used it has been removed: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/26eca99119982ba81b755edfc613030e4a1b19de#diff-a30171f546503974b947ac1bb16f4e75

Answer (score 0):

http://kirankanumuri.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-supressaccept-ssl-certificates.html

You can add the flag --trustAllSSLCertificates